Why are private data members of a const object not const?
As they can not be modified after the initialization by the constructor after all, am I missing something?
Real question:
class Maze {
private:
    struct Coordinate {
        int x, y;

        Coordinate(const int &x, const int &y): x(x), y(y) {}
    };

    const Coordinate size;

    bool* structure;

public:
    Maze(const int &size_x, const int &size_y):
    size(size_x, size_y) {
        structure = new bool[(size.x * 2 - 1)][(size.y * 2 - 1)];
    }
};

Compiling this with G++ (in C++17 standard) gives this error:

array size in new-expression must be constant

and

‘this’ is not a constant expression

Why?

In this context, it means a compile-time constant (not a const object which cannot be modified after initialization).

must be constant is somewhat confusing, and size.x is not a constant expression

They meant "compile-time constant".

new bool[x][y]; ≠ bool*.

the point of the error is that array sizes must be known at compile time (not that you can modify the value of a variable used to initialize an arrays size after initializating ot the array)

It's a confusing error message. The underlying problem is that array new allocates an array, but the code tries to allocate an array of arrays.

You can allocate a 1D array with new T[width*height], and then access it with ptr[y * width + x]. It would be better to use vectors though, either a 1D vector with the same size, or a vector<vector<T>>.

new bool[(size.x * 2 - 1)] would be fine, but you're trying to allocate an array of arrays, and the "inner" arrays must be of a size known at compile-time. I think you need to spend some time thinking deep thoughts about the differences between arrays and pointers.

try bool other_structure[size_x][size_y];. Understanding why this is and error is the answer to the quesiton in your title, and the first step to fully understand the error in your code.

To try to explain the message: a "constant expression" is an expression whose value is known at compile-time. An object whose value is determined at runtime is not a "constant expression" even if it is immutable (i.e. const).

I would seriously consider using std::vector<std::vector<bool> > (which, with sensible usage, will take care of memory allocation and deallocation for you AND can be resized based on runtime data) instead of explicitly allocating a 2D array of bools.    Just bear in mind that std::vector<bool> is a bit "special" (in the sense of being a bit different from other std::vectors)

If you want to create two-dimensional array (class member «structure»), the code should be something like this:
bool** structure;

…
Maze(int size_x, int size_y) :
    size(size_x, size_y) {
    size_t rows_count = size.x * 2 - 1;
    size_t cols_count = size.y * 2 - 1;
    structure = new bool*[rows_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows_count; ++i)
        structure[i] = new bool[cols_count];
}

Don’t forget to write destructor to free the memory.
You’d better use std::vector

If std::vector is a better solution, why not show that in the answer instead?

Explicit use of operator new should be avoided since C++11.

"the code should be .... you better use something else" hm?
